# Install Docker on Ubuntu 16.04: 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, docker

I get the following when trying to install Docker on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
michael@michael-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update                    
Err:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.32.250.25 443]

Reading package lists... Done                                                       

E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your software source is likely wrong. If you use the command listed [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) the command should look like:

```
add-apt-repository deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

This is also more or less the new line that is added to `/etc/apt/sources.lst`

Answer (score 0):

Secure source did not work for me; if you are having the same problem as myself you might want to try with the following repository link.

add following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```